# How to get employees with their past and current jobs in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I am new to NoSQL databases and so I'm struggling with the structure and the queries.

I am currently working with a company dataset in mongodb which has the following structure:

```
{
    "_id": "52cdef7c4bab8bd675297d8b",
    "name": "AdventNet",
    "permalink": "abc3",
    "category_code": "enterprise",
    "number_of_employees": 600,
    "founded_year": 1996,
    "relationships": [{
        "is_past": true,
        "title": "CEO and Co-Founder",
        "person": {
            "first_name": "Sridhar",
            "last_name": "Vembu",
            "permalink": "sridhar-vembu"
        }
    }, {
        "is_past": true,
        "title": "VP of Business Dev",
        "person": {
            "first_name": "Neil",
            "last_name": "Butani",
            "permalink": "neil-butani"
        }
    }, {
        "is_past": true,
        "title": "Western Regional OEM Sales Manager",
        "person": {
            "first_name": "Ian",
            "last_name": "Wenig",
            "permalink": "ian-wenig"
       }
    },
    ...
    }]
}
```

What I would like to achieve is to get a new collection with each employee name and all his/her past and current jobs, for example:

```
{
    "_id": "neil-butani",
    "first_name": "Neil",
    "last_name": "butani",
    "employments": [{
        "is_past": false,
        "title": "CEO and Co-Founder",
        "company_name": "AdventNet"
    }, {
        "is_past": true,
        "title": "VP of Business Dev",
        "company_name": "Example Inc.""
    }]
}
```

In SQL I would write query which joined the employees table with the companies table, but what operators and concept could or should I use to get the desired result in mongodb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `$unwind` and `$group` by `permalink` to collect all `employments` followed by `$out` to write into new collection.

Something like

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$relationships"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$relationships.person.permalink",
      "first_name": {
        "$first": "$relationships.person.first_name"
      },
      "last_name": {
        "$first": "$relationships.person.last_name"
      },
      "employments": {
        "$push": {
          "is_past": "$relationships.is_past",
          "title": "$relationships.title",
          "company_name": "$name"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$out": "new collection name"
  }
])
```